# Unable to domain restrict private YouTube videos using a brand account

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, google-plus, google-workspace-for-business, youtube-channel

I have a brand account with access to create a YouTube channel.

I uploaded a video and set it to private.

The problem is that I can't share this video with all emails of a particular domain, for example sharing it with everyone whose email domain is @company-name.com

It just allows me to add individual email addresses with whom I want to share the video.

How can I share a private video with emails from a specific domain?

Comment: For clarity: Do you use gsuite or do you just have a brand account controlled by a gmail or another non-google email address?

Comment: Im using GSuite

Comment: hm. I know this used to be a thing ([they announced it here](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2013/11/domain-restricted-videos-in-youtube.html)) but since the Google+ identities have been phased out in favor of Google Identities/Brand accounts.

Comment: Can you please help me out with how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: I do not use gSuite so I can't test it myself and I cannot find anything relevant in the help articles, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

YouTube has an option for domain restricted videos, but it's only available for Google Business, Education, and Government accounts.

> Google Apps users who use their Google+ identity in YouTube will now
>   have the option to post videos that are viewable only by others at
>   their domain. Domain-restricted videos can only be viewed through the
>   web UI at this time. You’ll see a field under the “Privacy Settings”
>   drop-down menu where you can add your domain to the list of people who
>   have access to view the video.
>
> **Editions included:**  Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government

Source - [G Suite Update Alerts: Domain-restricted videos in YouTube](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2013/11/domain-restricted-videos-in-youtube.html)

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this issue. The problem is the brand account. On your individual account you do have the domain-restricted video option, but not on the brand account.

I do not know if there is way to affiliate the brand to the domain or not.

Comment: I can confirm this is still an issue as of 2022; you have to use a non-Brand Account to get the domain restriction feature.